# Identify duplicates (two columns), sum it based on another column, and keep other variables in R

Tags: r, duplicates, plyr

I have a got a database with duplicate coordinates (latitude and longitude) and corresponding abundances of evidences, among other variables (see table below). I would like to remove these duplicates, but at the same time summing the corresponding abundances. Additionally, I would like to keep the information regarding the other variables available in the final data frame.

I could eliminate the duplicates and sum the corresponding abundances

```
data.2<-ddply(data,~lat + long,summarise, abund=sum(abund))
data.2<-data.2[-1,]
```

but have no idea how to keep the other variables (e.g year, method....) at the same time as a data frame.

[image]

Following is a reproducible example

```
id<-c('6916','7727','7728','7230')
method<-c('R','R','R','T')
year<-c(2012,2012,2012,2012)
lat<-c(-6.612,-6.611,-6.611,-6.610)
long<-c(30.638,30.607,30.607,30.609)
abund<-c(1,1,1,1)

df<-data.frame(id,method,year,lat,long,abund)
```

Comment: Try with `mutate` instead of `summarise` and then wrap with `unique`.  Using `dplyr` `data %>% group_by(lat, long) %>% mutate(abund = sum(abundd)) %>% ungroup %>% distinct(lat, long, .keep_all = TRUE)`

Comment: please add data and code so others can help.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked well, and I can assume that the rest of the data (no duplicates) is still kept in the dataframe with argument .keep_all=TRUE, right?

Answer (score 0):

A data.table solution follows below. Assuming that you want the `abund` tallies of duplicated `lat/long` entries to count towards the respective sum of `abund`.

```
require(data.table); setDT(df)

df[, abund := sum(abund), .(lat, long)]         # Sum abund across lat/long 
df = df[!duplicated(lat) & !duplicated(long)]   # Remove duplicate lat/long entries

> df
     id method year    lat   long abund
1: 6916      R 2012 -6.612 30.638     1
2: 7727      R 2012 -6.611 30.607     2
3: 7230      T 2012 -6.610 30.609     1
```

Comment: Thanks for helping! Juts to clarify, this approach only keeps records of the duplicates, right? It doesn't return it to the rest of the dataframe (the rows without duplicates?

Comment: No, it keeps all records, however with duplicate rows removed (in this case id == 7727). Compare it with your df sample.

Comment: Thanks, will test it with all data